# Check file encoding thanks to Azure Data Factory activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'd like to be able to check the encoding of a input file in the flow of my pipeline. Any idea about to do that thanks to one of the activity provided by Azure Data Factory?

Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not supported by any of the activities "on the box" at this time, but you are able to do that using other services with connectors available on ADF like Azure Function for example. But you will need to develop the algorithm to detect the encoding and an azure function service to do that ... (Of course other services like Azure Batch, Notebooks ... could be used)

*Saying that, it could be really usefull to add this information into the Get Metadata Activity (just posted the idea to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/37452187-add-encoding-into-the-get-a-file-s-metadata-activi)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the post !